# Cargar script de contenido "Playbuzz" en un WebView

Tags: android, ios, webview, webview-android

Trato de cargar contenido de un script de [**"playbuzz"**](https://www.playbuzz.com/) dentro de un `WebView`, encontré una forma de realizarlo, que es cargando el script en una pagina web:

```
String urlPlayBuzz = "http://www.jorgesys.com/playbuzzcontent.html";
webview.loadUrl(urlPlayBuzz);
```

### [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero mi requerimiento es cargar únicamente el script y desplegar el contenido:

```
String script = "<center style=\"width:100%;\"><script> (function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(d.getElementById(id))return;js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src='//embed.playbuzz.com/sdk.js' ;fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}(document, 'script' , 'playbuzz-sdk' ));</script><div class=\"playbuzz\" data-id=\"9ed89fec-22cb-441e-b2a3-69b3bd1e6953\" data-show-info=\"false\" data-show-share=\"false\" style=\"width:100%;height:56.25vw\"></div></center>";
```

Traté esta opcion:

```
    webview.loadUrl(script);
```

y también:

```
    webview.loadData(script,"text/html","UTF-8");
```

ambas sin éxito, solo me muestran el `WebView` en blanco:

[image]

Es importante comentar que si completo el path relativo que tiene el script del archivo `src='//embed.playbuzz.com/sdk.js'` , no funciona completamente.

**¿Como podría cargar correctamente un script de  ["playbuzz"](https://www.playbuzz.com/) dentro de un WebView?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré que a diferencia de otro scripts (por ejemplo twitter o instagram) el código embebido tiene definidos paths relativos, por ejemplo:

```
js.src='//embed.playbuzz.com/sdk.js'
```

Por lo tanto en este caso por medio del método:

> [loadDataWithBaseURL()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) Carga los datos dados en este WebView,
>   usando baseUrl como la URL base para el contenido. La URL base se usa
>   tanto para resolver URL relativas como para aplicar la misma política
>   de origen de JavaScript. El historyUrl se usa para la entrada del
>   historial.

se puede definir el path base el contenido,

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("https://embed.playbuzz.com.com", url, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

de esta forma se puede cargar el contenido para código embebido que contenga scripts con rutas relativas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]